# background image overlay too large

Tags: android, html, css

I have the following css to display a background image

```
height: 90%; /* or whatever, equal to the image you want 'watermarked' */
    width: 90%; /* as above */
    background-image: url('<?php echo "study/".$_SESSION['bkground_img']; ?>');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 1; /* Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE >= 9 (preview) */
    filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* for <= IE 8 */
    background-size: cover;
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
```

The problem I am having is that the background image is too big and is not fitting within the screen. I want it to change with the screen size and even for mobile phone

Answer (score 0):

add this css may be worked

```
   height: 90%; /* or whatever, equal to the image you want 'watermarked' */
width: 90%; /* as above */
background-image: url('<?php echo "study/".$_SESSION['bkground_img']; ?>');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
position: absolute;
opacity: 1; /* Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, IE >= 9 (preview) */
filter:alpha(opacity=50); /* for <= IE 8 */
background-size: cover;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
   margin: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some picture editing can help you. Also if your image is available, try to copy your image on x or y coordinates By using this code:

`body{
            background-image:url(background.jpg);
            background-repeat: repeat-y; /* or repeat-x, it is based on how you want */
}`

I hope this answer is useful for u :)